# Looking for software recommendation, airflow question. Want to evaluate vortex shedding, car hood or plane wing surface

Tags: physics

[image]
Insert of hood containing scoops to direct air flow in an organized fashion.  Need to evaluate upmost % of organized vortex shedding.  Less expensive than wind tunnel time.

Comment: Do a search for CFD software. CHAM do Phoenics, Also there are many others - not free and not cheap. Next you will ask if any are free. Just search.

Comment: There are free options like OpenFoam, but I cannot say if it would be less expensive than wind tunel time if you factor in things like learning to use the software.